# Performance analyser for C++ with GUI like jsperf

Tags: javascript, c++, performance-analysis, profiling

There's a nice tool in JS world called [`jsperf`](http://jsperf.com/convert-string-to-charcode-array). It allows one to profile several snippets of code at once to detemine which of them are most performant.

There's [a lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) of performance analysers for C++, but the ones I've seen were just console applications or IDE plugins for profiling.

Is there a performance analyser with similar interface?

Comment: Why do you ask? If your goal is to make your code as fast as possible, there's a misconception, at least 30 years old, that you have to analyze and measure the performance of its parts. That's wrong. You don't need to measure or analyze. All you have to do is let the slow parts naturally expose themselves, [*like this*](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18993/13902).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey `jsperf` is used to optimize e.g. loop kernels that are already known to be performance bottlenecks. It lets you compare several versions of the code to choose the most performant one. The question is not about searcing for slow parts of code at all. I've found VTune to be a good solution for C++ development, though I still have to guess amounts of iterations and filter deviating results to get statistically sound results, while `jsperf` does this internally.

Comment: If you know where to look, it's an easy problem - just time the different versions. The more common situation is a) there are multiple speedups in the code, b) you don't know where they are, and c) they hide from profilers (including VTune), leading you to think the code is optimal when it isn't. [*Some detail, in particular why "statistical soundness" is not useful, and explaining what **does** work.*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The whole problem is in that "just" word you used. There's no tools for that. The post you've linked is about soundness of your "tiresome for no good reason profiling via debugger" method, while I'm talking about statistical soundness of time measurement results. If OS scheduler switches the currently running program while you measure run time of the program, the run time will be a bit larger, and you will not even know how much the value was tainted.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The best method I know is "minimal N run times of several runs of K iterations of algorithm, correct K after several runs to get statistically better results" method was developed, and I'm no good in doing it by hand.

Comment: We're talking about different things. You're talking about measuring small differences, like 10+/-2%. I'm talking about finding big problems like 30% which, when removed, make remaining problems 100/70 = 1.4 times bigger. Find and fix 6 of these, and you're over 8 times faster. Miss any, and you're not.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Yep, totally different things. I have a numeric code that has a highly optmized short part that constitutes 80% of the run time. The best I can do is win several microseconds here and there (in no way depending on performance of those parts of code) to make it faster. There's no way your approach could help me determine that given code change actually boosts performance. That's what `jsperf` is for when it comes to JS development. The question is about C++ alternatives.

Comment: Why can't you put your "several snippets" into a single program, and profile that?